# Lambda not a property type when passing property

Tags: c#, lambda

I have the following class:

```
public class Errors<T> : Errors
{
    public void Add(Expression<Func<T>> property, string message)
    {
        base.Add(((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name, message);
    }
}
```

Which I then try and invoke like this:

```
Errors<User> e = new Errors<User>();
e.Add(x => x.Name, "Name must be entered.");
```

When I attempt to compile, I get the following error:

`Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type`

Where is my definition wrong? The error occurs on the `e.Add` method call, not on the overload.

Comment: What is your base class? It looks like you are trying to pass a string to the first expression of `Errors.Add` (the non-generic one). That is probably where this is failing. Also `Func<T>` is a lambda taking nothing and returning a `T`.

Comment: @Guvante the compilation error is on the line `e.Add(x => x.Name, "Name must be entered.")`

Comment: `Func<T>` should take no argument and return `T`, in this case `User`. Did you mean to use `Func<T, object>`?

Comment: @Sam: Sorry my wording was off, I meant that the first argument of Add in the base class was a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've specified `Func<T>` in your overload, which should take no argument and return `T` (in this case, `User`). You're passing a lambda which looks more like `Func<T, object>` - it accepts a `T` parameter and returns *something*.

I imagine your `Errors` base class has a function like this:

```
public class Errors{    
    public void Add(string propertyName, string message) {
        // implementation here
    }    
}
```

Which is what the error is talking about. It's trying to match your lambda to the parameters of that overload, because it doesn't match the `Func<T>` you specified in your generic class's overload.

So, I think your overload should be:

```
public void Add(Expression<Func<T, object>> property, string message)
```

Comment: I think you should put the answer's most important information (the last paragraph) in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks so much. Exactly what I was after.

Comment: Sam, glad to help. @JuanLopes I feel the answer is short enough that it doesn't matter. Added a bit more detail though.